# WebRequest.GetResponse Error: Underlying Connection - C# Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is my code for this HttpWebRequest. I was wondering why I can use this code on google.com or facebook.com.

While on this particular site which is below, I got this error `The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.`

What else do I need to add in my code to make this work? do you guys have an idea? I searched that I need certificate or trusted certificates to make an http request, but how can I implement this on my code?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest MyWebRequest;
    WebResponse MyWebResponse;
    StreamReader sr;
    string strHTML;
    StreamWriter sw;

    MyWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://qiita.com/naoki_mochizuki/items/3fda1ad6594c11d7b43c");
    MyWebResponse = MyWebRequest.GetResponse();
    sr = new StreamReader(MyWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
    strHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();

    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);  

    sw = File.CreateText(@path +"\\"+TextBox1.Text+"");
    sw.WriteLine(strHTML);

    sw.Close();               

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the CreateHttp static helper method instead of Create.

The reason for this is that you have a property `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` which is a delegate that will let you allow to customize the action on certification validation.

In the case below, i have set it to statically return true to proceed or allow the request.

```
HttpWebRequest MyWebRequest;
WebResponse MyWebResponse;
StreamReader sr;
string strHTML;
StreamWriter sw;
MyWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://qiita.com/naoki_mochizuki/items/3fda1ad6594c11d7b43c");
MyWebRequest.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (snd, cert, chain, err) => true;
```

Comment: how to declare the servercertificatevalidationcallback? using system.certificate? something like that?

Comment: I do not understand `how to declare the servercertificatevalidationcallback`, what do you mean? ServerCertificateValidationCallback is a member property of HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Net.WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'ServerCertificateValidationCallback' and no extension method 'ServerCertificateValidationCallback' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Please show my edit. variable MyWebRequest please change the type to `HttpWebRequest` from WebRequest.

Comment: Error 1 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'CreateHttp' 

Error 2 A local variable named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sender', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: You should have changed the delegate param names. This should give you no problem.

Comment: this really doesn't make sense, I mean this error

Error 1 'System.Net.WebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'CreateHttp'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168547/discussion-between-ngeksyo-and-christian-quirante).

Answer (score 1):

I added this code to solve this issue

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```